# Problem validating XML with XSD facet pattern

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xmllint

I am trying to validate my XML String against an XSD using xmllint but I keep getting this error:

> file_0.xml:6: element No: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.mrq.gouv.qc.ca/T5}No': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'NP666666' is not accepted by the pattern '(NP|np)d{6}'."
>
> "file_0.xml:6: element No: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.mrq.gouv.qc.ca/T5}No': 'NP666666' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.

I actually get 34 errors but they are all alike. Every other part passes but the numbers.
My code is on JavaScript and I'm hand-making the objects to pass to XML.

XML :

```
    <P><Annee>2019</Annee>
<TypeEnvoi>1</TypeEnvoi>

<Preparateur><No>NP999999</No>
<Nom1>Garderie Papillons</Nom1>

<Adresse><Ligne1>5 Street name</Ligne1>
<Ville>Toronto</Ville>
<Province>QC</Province>
<CodePostal>G5T6R4</CodePostal>
</Adresse>
</Preparateur>
<NoCertification>RQ-19-99-999</NoCertification>
<NomLogiciel>NomLogiciel</NomLogiciel>
<CourrielResponsable>CourrielResponsable</CourrielResponsable>
<IdPartenaireReleves>1234567891234567</IdPartenaireReleves>
<IdProduitReleves>1234567891234567</IdProduitReleves>

</P>
```

XSD:

```
 <xsd:element
name="P"
type="PStruct" />
<xsd:complexType
name="PStruct">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element
    name="Annee"
    type="AnImpositionType">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="TypeEnvoi"
    type="Indicateur1-4-6Type">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="Preparateur">
            
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element
          name="No">
                        
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction
              base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:pattern
                value="(NP|np)\d{6}" />
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element
          name="Type"
          type="Indicateur1-3Type"
          minOccurs="0">
                        
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element
          name="Nom1"
          type="Char30Type">
                        
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element
          name="Nom2"
          type="Char30Type"
          minOccurs="0">
                        
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element
          name="Adresse"
          type="Adresse2Struct"
          minOccurs="0" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="Informatique"
    type="RessourceStruct"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="Comptabilite"
    type="RessourceStruct"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="NoCertification">
            
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction
        base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:pattern
          value="RQ-\d{2}-\w{2}-\w{3}" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="NomLogiciel"
    type="Char40Type"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="VersionLogiciel"
    type="Char15Type"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="CourrielResponsable"
    type="Char60Type"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="CourrielLangue"
    type="LangueType"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="IdPartenaireReleves"
    type="Char16FixeType">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="IdProduitReleves"
    type="Char16FixeType">
            
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element
    name="NoCasEssai"
    type="Char25Type"
    minOccurs="0">
            
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimum but complete XSD rather than an malformed fragment starting with `name="P"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(NP|np)d{6}` matches `NPdddddd` or `npdddddd`.

You probably meant `(NP|np)\d{6}`, which would match digits rather than literal `d` letters.

---

**Update based on exchange in comments:**
It appears that the XSD was being processed as a string such that the `\d{6}` was interpreted as being escaped to just `d{6}` prior to being used in validation.

Comment: In the XSD it stands at \d{6} it just doesnt appear in the error

Comment: That's one reason it's important to post the XML, XSD, etc ([mcve]).  I see you've now added a fragment of the XSD, but it starts in the middle of an opening element tag.  Please post a well-formed, complete XSD.  Thanks.

Comment: I have tested your theory about the NPdddddd and yea for some reason it doesnt see the \ so it works with the 6ds

Comment: If the XSD or its parts are being processed as a string somewhere, perhaps the original `\d` is being interpreted and replaced as a literal `d` prior to being used in validation.

Comment: yea i think i just fixed it by placing two of the backslash.   ill do the same to the rest of them and let you know <3 thanks